# PHP update database with checkbox

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I am a newbie on ajax and I try to change a value on my database pending a checkbox. I am using following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(id_submit, check){
        check = (check==true ? 1 : 0);
        var url = "check_validate.php.php?id_submit="+id_submit+"&chkYesNo="+check;
            if(windows.XMLHttpRequest){
                req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if(windows.ActiveXObject){
                req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
                req.open("GET", url, true);
                req.send(null);
        }
</script>
```

Then I get a other value from my database:

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
    $check = $row['checkbox'];
    $id_submits = $zeile['id_submits']; 

?>
        <td style='text-align:center;width:120px;'>
        <input name="check" type="checkbox" id="check_<?php echo $id_submits; ?>" value="<?php echo $id_submits; ?>" onclick="check(<?php echo $id_submits; ?>, this.checked);" 
        <?php if($check == 1){ echo "checked"; }else{ echo "";} ?>/>
        </td><?php
```

And then I have my "check_validate.php"

```
$id_submit = $_GET['id_submit'];
$chkYesNo = $_GET['chkYesNo'];

require_once('config.php');    

$sql = "UPDATE table1
SET checkbox =$chkYesNo WHERE id_submits = $id_submits";
$result = mysqli_query( $link, $sql );
```

But nothing happens on my database, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you print out `$id_submit` and `$chkYesNo`, what do you see?

Comment: One (*most probable*) possibility `SET checkbox =$chkYesNo WHERE id_submits = $id_submits` which should read as `SET checkbox ='$chkYesNo' WHERE id_submits = '$id_submits'` and I doubt the variables are integers, so you will need to use quotes as shown.

Comment: Did you ever close the `while` block?

Comment: Where should I print them out? I tried the check_validate.php without ajax and the data on the database change. Of course I close the while-block.

Comment: I noticed a few `id_submit` in singular form, and may need to be changed to `id_submits`? As in `function update(id_submit, check)` and `check_validate.php.php?id_submit="+id_submit+"&chkYesNo="` @user2554342 - Other than those, I can't say for certain.

Comment: Print it out right before your `require_once...`

Comment: Thanks Fed -ii-: I changed it to id_submit. Where do I see the echo in the check_validate.php?

Comment: I made an alert(id_submit) after check = (check==true ? 1 : 0) and it shows the number 1392151360.787 instead of 1392151360.7870. Why does it delete the last number "0"???

Comment: Because trailing zeroes after a decimal place have no numeric significance, and JavaScript is treating the value as a number. If you need that extra zero, you need to force the value to be a string.

Comment: Thanks Brian. How can I do this? I tried var check = String(check), but It shows the same. :-(

Comment: and check = check.toString(): shows the same result without the zero at the end